# ReactJs 18: new auto-batching causes component to not be rendered in Karma integration test

Tags: reactjs, typescript, karma-jasmine, react-18

I have an application where I just render React Components using the createElement method like so:

```
public static render<T>(target: HTMLElement, reactComponent: FC<T>, attrs: T) {
        const root = createRoot(target);

        root.render(
            React.createElement(reactComponent, attrs),
        );
    }
```

The code works fine in browser, but as soon as I test my whole page (which includes the component), the component is not rendered.
The FC code is only called at the end of the test, performing all at once.

I am testing my application using Karma/Jasmine, using ReactJS 18 (which has native auto-batching), my component is not rendered until the end of the test.

The code above has been modified to use flushSync() to make it render immediately, but the flushSync also needs to be done on any of my hooks, which feels like an overkill.

```
public static render<T>(target: HTMLElement, reactComponent: FC<T>, attrs: T) {
        const root = createRoot(target);

        // Any state change needs to be sync for Karma test purposes.
        // In reality, we should not need it.
        // React 18 now batches changes, which Karma does not like.
        flushSync(() => root.render(
            React.createElement(reactComponent, attrs),
        ));
    }
```

Is there a way to force the rendering in integration test (karma) without the need to change all my code to use flushSync?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So I found the solution to my problem.

I created a class as follows, and call this flush method before asserting:

```
import { act } from "react-dom/test-utils";

export default class ReactJsActions {
    public static async flush() {
        await act(async () => {
            // tslint:disable-next-line: no-unused-expression
            await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve));
        });
    }
}
```

Here is an example of how I use it:

```
it("stuff", async () => {
    [code that would cause the state of the react component to change]
    await ReactJsActions.flush();
    expect([something]).toEqual([something]);
});
```

[act](https://reactjs.org/docs/test-utils.html#act) is used to prepare the component for assertions, usually, in reactjs test using the usual framework, you would put the action being performed within the `act` lambda method, then assert after it. On my case, I was performing an action that reactjs did not have control with, so putting the action inside was doing nothing.

Putting `await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve))` within the act resolves the issue.

From my understanding, the new Promise with `setTimeout(resolve)` with no time will allow any other setTimeout to execute, which I believe the `scheduler` heavily relies on, and the scheduler would be used for batching.

Please share if anyone has a more pertinent reason for why it works.